# Verificar estado de la suscripción auto renovable Xcode Swift IAP

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy implementando compras dentro de la App, específicamente suscripción auto renovable en Xcode 11.5 utilizando StoreKit

He estado realizando distintas pruebas a traves de SandBox, pero necesito saber como se verifica el estado de la suscripción para conocer si esta aun se encuentra activa cada vez que se inicie  la App y así habilitar o deshabilitar el contenido de pago.

No encuentro información sobre como se implementa esta funcionalidad.
Agradezco por favor si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar esto.

Saludos.

```
class IAPService: NSObject {
    
    private override init() {}
    static let shared = IAPService()
    
    var products = [SKProduct]()
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
    
    //view para mensajes
    var view: UIView!
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var config_premium       : String!
    
    func getProducts(view: UIView) {
        self.view = view
        let products: Set = [IAPProduct.autoRenewingSubscription.rawValue /*,
                             IAPProduct.consumable.rawValue,
                             IAPProduct.nonConsumable.rawValue,
                             IAPProduct.nonRenewingSubscription.rawValue*/]
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        paymentQueue.add(self)
        
    }
    
    
    func purchase(product: IAPProduct) {
        guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }).first else { return }
        //let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
        //paymentQueue.add(payment)
        
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
            paymentQueue.add(payment)
            
        }else{
            self.view.makeToast("El dispositivo no es compatible con Apple Pay.")
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func restorePurchases() {
        print("===== Proceso de restaurar")
        paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
        
    }
    
    
}



extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        for product in response.products {
            
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.price)
            print(product.priceLocale)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            
        }
    }
    
    
}


extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            
            //print(transaction.transactionState)
            print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
            switch transaction.transactionState {
                case .deferred:
                    //Se ha detenido la compra porque se debe tomar alguna acción externa como confirmar la compra cuando se usa control parental en el dispositivo. Se puede informar al usuario y esperar a que llegue otro evento.
                    print("===== deferred")
                    self.view.makeToast("deferred.")
                    //queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    break
                
                case .failed:
                    //La compra ha fallado, podemos consultar el error en la propiedad error de la transacción.
                    print("===== failed")
                    self.view.makeToast("Proceso fallido.")
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    break
                
                case .purchased:
                    //La compra se ha realizado correctamente y ya podemos ejecutarla en nuestra aplicación o informar a la plataforma sobre la misma.
                    print("===== purchased, Habilitar contenido")
                    self.view.makeToast("Felicidades... Ya eres usuario Premium.")
                    //HABILITAR PREMIUM
                    defaults.set("S", forKey: "CONFIG_PREMIUM")
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    break
                
                case .purchasing:
                    //Indica que la compra sigue pendiente de ser procesa por el AppStore, debemos esperar a que cambie el estado y se vuelva llamar a la función para tomar una acción.
                    print("===== purchasing")
                    self.view.makeToast("Procesando compra....")
                    break
                
                case .restored:
                    //En el caso, que veremos a continuación, de haber restaurado una compra indica que se ha realizado de forma correcta y podemos ejecutar la acción pertinente como en el caso comprado.
                    print("===== restored")
                    self.view.makeToast("Compras restauradas")
                    //HABILITAR PREMIUM
                    defaults.set("S", forKey: "CONFIG_PREMIUM")
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    break
                
                default:
                    print("===== ESTADO NO VALIDO")
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    queue.remove(self)
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}



extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
    func status() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .deferred:     return "deferred"
            case .failed:       return "failed"
            case .purchased:    return "purchased"
            case .purchasing:   return "purchasing"
            case .restored:     return "restored"
            default:            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código?

Comment: @Bicho Hola, agregó mi clase IAPService que es la encargada de realizar el proceso de suscripción. Necesito saber como se verifica el estado de la suscripción para conocer si esta aun se encuentra activa cada vez que se inicia la App. Saludos.

Comment: Te faltan algunas funciones; aquí está todo: https://blog.apphud.com/swift-tutorial-subscriptions/